# How many numbers are divisible by n and m in the range [l, r](inclusive)?

Tags: algorithm, math, number-theory

I have four numbers n,m,l,r;

For a range between numbers l and r.

How can I find the total numbers whose % with n and m is 0 i.e. how many numbers between land r are divisible by n and m?

Comment: What have **you** tried / researched so far? Share your ideas / findings / code.

Comment: I tried so many times but I can not create a solution. if numbers is only one such that only n or only m it is easy..just (r/m)-(l-1)/m. but for two numbers i can not find a solution..

Comment: What is GCD of n,m?

Comment: Can you share at least ONE of the things you tried?

Comment: I am new at stack overflow that's why maybe I am not familiar with how I ask for help and how I write e questions for seeking help? that's emotional stuff come to your point:- this is my code:-https://ideone.com/2Coh9b.. it does not give me the correct solution.

Comment: Hi @MehediMahbub, there's plenty of advise on writing a good question in the [help]. Please add your code as well as your desired results and how you've tried to debug to the question itself using [edit].

Answer (score 1):

For a number to be divisible by both n and m, it must be divisible by the LCM (Least common multiple) of n and m. If a number is not divisible by the LCM of n and m, then it will not be divisible by at least one of n or m. Thus, we have a path to solving this problem: To determine the number of integers between `l` and `r` which are divisible by both `n` and `m`, we can count the number of integers between `l` and `r` which are divisible by `LCM(n, m)` which is `r/lcm - l/lcm`.

The LCM of two integers is calculated as `n / GCD(n, m) * m`. Many languages have a built-in GCD implementation, but if yours doesn't, you can certainly find one online. Best of luck!

Comment: This is my code:-https://ideone.com/7U5l2d.here I use l-1 because the problem says l and r inclusive.. but this code gives me a wrong answer on test 24..the problem is private so that's why I can not give this problem here..but I think the main problem is the problem constraints .here n,m,l,r<=1e18 I think that's why this solution sometimes gives overflow..can you please how can I optimize with this long constraints.